# Enum auto in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I've read that when using Enums in python 3 you have the option to use auto to automatically ennumerate the elements. It seems that in python2 this is not possible.

However I found [this doc](https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/enum.html#autonumber) which permits auto numeration. However it is not working well

In the docs we have

```
class AutoNumber(Enum):
    def __new__(cls):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

class Color(AutoNumber):
    red = ()
    green = ()
    blue = ()
```

Then in the docs they give us as example

```
Color.green.value == 2
```

and yes, green give us 2. But red give us 3! and blue give us 1

so the elements are of value 3,2,1  and not 0,1,2 or 1,2,3 as I assumed.

I've tried to modify AutoNumber without success.

How can I get the correct numeration?  (0,1,2) (1,2,3) or (-1,0,1) is ok

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that:

- in Python 2, dicts are not ordered
- in Python 2, there is no `__prepare__` on metaclasses (to remember the ordering for is)

If you are using Python 2 you should use the [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) library<sup>1</sup>, and specify the `_order_` attribute, like so:

```
from aenum import Enum, auto

class Color(Enum):
    _order_ = 'red green blue'
    red = auto()
    green = auto()
    blue = auto()
```

---

In cases where you have a lot of names, you can also use the functional API form:

```
Color = Enum('Color', """
    red
    green
    blue
    magenta
    white
    """)
```

The names just need to be white-space separated, and they will be valued starting from `1`.

--

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: thanks. My problem is that I have an enum with more than 200 elements. I dont think having to specify all these elements in __order__ will be very practical...

Comment: @KansaiRobot: I updated my answer to include a method that will work for you.